# How to create a testng xml file using jenkins

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am displaying a HTML page to the user where I am providing users the options to select multiple test cases form jenkins. And based on the users selection I need to generate a XML file.Is it possible to generate a XMl based on user selection and If it is then what needs to be done to create XML.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to take the test names (exact method names) or class names from the user, let Jenkins pass it as arguments to your main method.

In the main you can build the code based on the arguments to invoke testng [programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically).